# How to display AlertController in UiView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uialertcontroller

new to Swift. Below code is executed without error but in the console it shows a message. Is it an error message and how to fix it? Is it required to be fixed when sending app for review.

Thanks

This is my App structure :

```
VC(1)     -->  goto -->    VC(2)
```

In VC(1) I have:

- BtnGo
- UiLabelMsg
- UitableView

I created a Link to VC(2) : Control-Drag BtnGo to VC(2)

I named the segue : SegueToVC2

**What I wanted to do**:

I need to pass a string to VC2. Before passing check if user made a selection.

in PrepareForSegue,

```
override func PrepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    var strchk: String = UIlabelMsg.text!

    if strchk.isEmpty {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert",message:" No Selection made",
           preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.AddAction(UIAlertction(title: "OK",style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default,hanlder: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil ) 

    } else {

    if (segue.Identifier =="SegueToVC2") {

        var targetVC = segue.destinationViewControl as! VC2
        targetVC.strMsg = UILabelMsg.text
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

in the console, it shows this:

> UIView : 0x7fdfc25668c0; frame =(0,0,375,667); autoresize = w+h; layer
>   = 's windows is not equal to 's View's Window!

I have these questions

How come I don't need to write code for BtnGo when I use `prepareForSegue`?
if I have more than 2 button?  these 2 will handle by Segue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UIView` have not `presentViewController` method, what's the `self`? You can using window of `UIView` to presenting.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No Selection made", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

**EDIT:** Possible you need to override the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to check the `UIlabelMsg.text`.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var strchk: String = UIlabelMsg.text!
    if strchk.isEmpty {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert",message:" No Selection made",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: window? is not a member. The above function is inside PrepareForSegue

Comment: @ Banings, read it. It seems the problem is not fixed using your suggestion. When I select an item and press BtnGo, there is no error. When there is no selection and press BtnGo, there is Alert Msg but also the error code as above in the console.

Comment: try this:`UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Problem not solved. got error Msg : Attempt to present UIalertController whose view is not in the windows hierarchy. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: the first solution works fine for me, however I did a little more :
`if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController   {
                        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true) {
                            
                        }`